# PHP: Generate Carbon array with opening and closing times (per day)

Tags: php, laravel, date, time, php-carbon

#### The desired result

I would like to have an associative array that contains a range of times (between opening and closing times) with an interval of 15 minutes. For example:

```php
[
    '2017-01-16' => [ // Start of the week (Monday)
        '08:00', // Opening time
        '08:15',
        '08:30',
        // Etc..
        '18:00', // Closing time
    ],
    '2017-01-17' => [ // Tuesday
        '10:00', // Opening time
        '10:15',
        '10:30',
        // Etc..
        '22:00', // Closing time
    ],

    // For every day in the week.
];
```

Another thing I would like to be able to do, is: Take a range of times (e.g. `09:00` - `10:00`) and remove it from the array (at a specific date key)

#### The steps I made (so far)

I have an array that looks just like the one above. But.. it starts with `00:00` and ends at `23:45`. With the following code (mainly from another question at Stackoverflow):

```php
private function generateDateRange(Carbon $start_date, Carbon $end_date)
{
    $dates = [];

    while ($start_date->lte($end_date)) {

        if(! array_key_exists($start_date->format('Y-m-d'), $dates)) {
            $dates[$start_date->format('Y-m-d')] = [];
        } else {

            array_push($dates[$start_date->format('Y-m-d')], $start_date->format('H:i'));

            if(in_array($start_date->format('H:i'), $dates[$start_date->format('Y-m-d')])) {
                $start_date->addMinutes(15);
            } else {
                $start_date->addDay();
            }


        }
    }

    return $dates;
}

$start = Carbon::now()->startOfWeek();
$end = Carbon::now()->endOfWeek();

$range = $this->generateDateRange($start, $end);
```

#### My question

How can I do this in PHP (Laravel)? I am planning to make this (more) dynamic by using a database. But first I want to have a working basic.

Does someone know what I could do to reach the desired result?

Comment: What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: As the array under **The desired result**. It should have every day of the week as the key, and that key contains a range of time (with an interval of 15 minutes) between the time of opening and closing. That should be dynamic for every day (key).

Comment: Ah yes sorry i though that was your source. So you want to pass in a start date and time (eg '2017-01-16 08:00') and end time (eg '2017-01-16 18:00') and get an array with each 15 minute slot in between?

Comment: Exactly. And that should be a dynamic opening and closing range for each day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
private function generateDateRange(Carbon $start_date, Carbon $end_date,$slot_duration = 15)
{
    $dates = [];
    $slots = $start_date->diffInMinutes($end_date)/$slot_duration;

    //first unchanged time
    $dates[$start_date->toDateString()][]=$start_date->toTimeString();

    for($s = 1;$s <=$slots;$s++){

        $dates[$start_date->toDateString()][]=$start_date->addMinute($slot_duration)->toTimeString();

    }

    return $dates;
}
```

Comment: Where do I say that a specific day should start at `08:00` and end at `18:00`?

Comment: pass `$start_date = '2017-01-16 08:00'`